# Opening files referenced with relative pathnames in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Often, I am editing files that reference other files, and I would like to be able to Cmd-click the filenames to open the referenced file.

An example would be a configuration file that points to another config file, cf. the following JSON snippet:

```js
    "structureDefinitionFilename": {
        "doc": "Filename of the Structure definitions",
        "default": "./structureDefinition.json"
    },
```

When my cursor is on the `./structureDefinition.json`, I would like to be able to run a command that opens that file. (I am not using the mouse a lot, so I was just mentioning Cmd-click as an example.)

Another example would be Python source code which opens a data file:

```py
with open('data/structures.lst') as f:
   ...
```

Again, it would be nice to be able to quickly open `data/structures.lst`.

Is there any built-in method or an extension that allows this?

Comment: You might find this useful https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jack89ita.open-file-from-path.

Comment: Thanks, @DibakarAditya; unfortunately, the extension does not yet seem do what I want. But it is an extremely close match, so I opened an issue about my use case: https://github.com/Jack89ita/vscode-open-file-from-path/issues/13